# Install python package in Notepad++ with pythonscript

Tags: python, notepad++, python-module

I have the PythonScript plugin working in NPP. I'd like to use the `python-dateutil` package/module.
I've tried unzipping it in `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\PythonScript` and `.\lib` but I still get:

```
ImportError: No module named dateutil
```

I don't have a stand-alone python installation.

Where should the package be installed?
Do I need to run something or rename the directory to install it properly?

Comment: Install it with `python setup.py install` after changing to a directory you've unzipped it into. It can be a temporary directory.

Comment: I don't have a standalone python installation, only python27.dll in the NPP PythonScript plugin.

I tried running this on the console within NPP:

execfile('C:\PROGRA~1\Notepad++\plugins\PythonScript\python-dateutil-2.2\setup.py')

But got this:

ImportError: No module named setuptools

Comment: Since it's a pure Python module, try copying _just_ the `dateutil` directory (along with its `zoneinfo` subdirectory) from the unzipped distribution into `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\PythonScript\lib` directory. If that doesn't work, try copying them into the `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\config` directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment from @martineau is correct.

Here's what I did:

1. Download the 1.5 package from http://labix.org/python-dateutil
   (1.5 because you want it compatible with Python 2.x)
2. Copy the dateutil directory from the archive to the Notepad++ directory, `plugins\PythonScript\lib` - this is probably `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\PythonScript\lib`, or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\PythonScript\lib`, but could be elsewhere.  Look at where Notepad++ is installed if you're not sure.
3. import dateutil now works, and you can use the various features.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of PythonScript*

Comment: Apart of being the right answer, +1 for this useful plugin you made :)

Answer (score 0):

Plugin directory for Notepad++ is the usual. Thonny Python IDE supports the ability to install plugins from PyPi or from file to the python directory instead of trying to do it through Notepad++.